# X Axis Label Change according to vector

Tags: r, plot, statistics, label

Hello back everyone after being away for a while!!

Im having this problem atm that you can help me with.

I need to change the X axis Index so instead of displaying number it displays the month

This is what im having now

[image]

And this is how i wanted to look like

[image]

This is the code im using.

```
mes_totales <- c(total_septiembre, total_octubre)
plot(mes_totales, main = "Ganancia x mes", xlab = "Mes", ylab = "Ganancia")
```

And this is the Data.

```
> print(mes_totales)
[1]  1260 11700
> names(mes_totales) <- c("septiembre", "octubre")
> print(mes_totales)
septiembre    octubre 
      1260      11700
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: See `?axis` and `axes = FALSE` in the `plot` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
plot(mes_totales, xaxt="n", xlab="Mes", main="Ganancia x mes", ylab="Ganancia")
axis(1, at=1:2, labels=c('"septiembre", "octubre")
```

You add xaxt="n" to the plot statement. That allows you to define your own x-axis in the next statement. The x-axis is 1, if you want to define the y-axis you would use axis(2....). It worked for me.